# R append dataframe name to each of its columns within a list of dataframes

Tags: r

I want to append the dataframe-name to each of its columns in the following list of dataframes:

```
df1 <- tibble(V1=c(1, 1, 3, 1),
                V2=c(2, 1, 2, 2),
                V3=c(4, 1, 1, 2))
df2 <- tibble(V1=c(1, 1, 3, 1),
                V2=c(2, 1, 2, 2),
                V3=c(4, 1, 1, 2))
df <- list(df1, df2)
names(df) <- c("df1", "df2")
df
```

This is how I would like it to look:

```
$df1
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  df1_V1 df1_V2 df1_V3
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1      1      2      4
2      1      1      1
3      3      2      1
4      1      2      2

$df2
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  df2_V1 df2_V2 df2_V3
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1      1      2      4
2      1      1      1
3      3      2      1
4      1      2      2
```

I have tried:

```
    appendDFnameToColumns <- function(df, prefix = "", sep = "") {
      colnames(df) <- paste(prefix, colnames(df), sep = sep) 
      df
      }
    
    df <- map(df, appendDFnameToColumns, 
                             prefix = names(df$.),
                             sep ="_")
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `tidyverse` approach with `purrr`s `imap` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

imap(df,~rename_with(.x, function(x) paste(.y, x, sep = '_')))

#$df1
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  df1_V1 df1_V2 df1_V3
#   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1      1      2      4
#2      1      1      1
#3      3      2      1
#4      1      2      2

#$df2
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  df2_V1 df2_V2 df2_V3
#   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1      1      2      4
#2      1      1      1
#3      3      2      1
#4      1      2      2
```

Or in base R you can use `Map` :

```
Map(function(x, y) setNames(x, paste(y, names(x), sep = '_')), df, names(df))
```

Answer (score 3):

With `purrr`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
names(df) %>% 
    map(function(dtf) {get(dtf) %>% rename_with(~paste0(dtf,"_",.))})
[[1]]
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  df1_V1 df1_V2 df1_V3
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1      1      2      4
2      1      1      1
3      3      2      1
4      1      2      2

[[2]]
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  df2_V1 df2_V2 df2_V3
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1      1      2      4
2      1      1      1
3      3      2      1
4      1      2      2
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rename` with `!!!`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
map2(df, names(df), ~ .x %>% 
       rename(!!! setNames(names(.), str_c(.y, names(.), sep="_"))))
```

-output

```
#$df1
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  df1_V1 df1_V2 df1_V3
#   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1      1      2      4
#2      1      1      1
#3      3      2      1
#4      1      2      2

#$df2
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  df2_V1 df2_V2 df2_V3
#   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1      1      2      4
#2      1      1      1
#3      3      2      1
#4      1      2      2
```